# "No route to host" with ssl but not with telnet

Tags: linux, ssl, firewall, telnet

I have a strange problem with connecting to a https site from one of my servers.

When I type:

```
 telnet puppet 8140
```

I am presented with a standard telnet console and can talk to the Server as always:

```
Connected to athena.hidden.tld.
Escape character is '^]'.
GET / HTTP/1.1
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html><head>
<title>400 Bad Request</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Bad Request</h1>
<p>Your browser sent a request that this server could not understand.<br />
Reason: You're speaking plain HTTP to an SSL-enabled server port.<br />
Instead use the HTTPS scheme to access this URL, please.<br />
<blockquote>Hint: <a href="https://athena.hidden.tld:8140/"><b>https://athena.hidden.tld:8140/</b></a></blockquote></p>
<hr>
<address>Apache/2.2.16 (Debian) Server at athena.hidden.tld Port 8140</address>
</body></html>
Connection closed by foreign host.
```

But when I try to connect to the same host and port with ssl:

```
openssl s_client -connect puppet:8140
```

It is not working

```
connect: No route to host
connect:errno=113
```

I am confused. At first it sounded like a firewall problem but this could not be, could it? Because this would also prevent the telnet connection.

As Firewall I am using ferm on both servers. 
The systems are debian squeeze vm-boxes.

**[edit 1]**

Even when I try to connect directly with the IP address:

```
openssl s_client -connect 198.51.100.1:8140 #address exchanged
connect: No route to host
connect:errno=113
```

Bringing down the firewalls on both hosts with

```
service ferm stop
```

is also not helping.

But when I do

```
openssl s_client -connect localhost:8140
```

on the server machine it is connecting fine.

**[edit 2]**

if I connect to the IP with telnet it also is not working.

```
telnet 198.51.100.1 8140
Trying 198.51.100.1...
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: No route to host
```

The confusion might come from IPv6. I have IPv6 on all my hosts. It seems that telnet uses IPv6 by default and this works.
For example:

```
telnet -6 puppet 8140
```

works but

```
telnet -4 puppet 8140
```

does not work. So there seems to be a problem with the IPv4 route. openssl seems to only (or by default) use IPv4 and therefore fails but telnet uses IPv6 and succeeds.

Comment: is your local and remote machine in the same subnet?

Comment: And just for completeness, **from the same client from which you did openssl s_client -connect 198.51.100.1:8140 above**, can you cut-and-paste the output of `telnet 198.51.100.1 8140`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can you check whether you can actually ping the target host? (IPv4) It seems that

- your IPv4 connection is broken
- there is an AAAA and an A record
- telnet manages to prefer IPv6
- openssl avoids IPv6

This might merely be an issue boiling down to IPv4 connections not working to the target host. Is your IPv4 routing OK on both machines?

Comment: the problem was indeed the IPv4 routing.
There the firewall on the VM-Host blocked the communication between VMs on different VM-Hosts.
I found this out using traceroute.

Answer (score 1):

As you note, it looks like you're running up against a lack of ipv6 support in openssl.  An [LWN article](https://lwn.net/Articles/486369/) gives some background, but it looks like your easiest solution (short of rebuilding a custom patched openssl) is to switch to [gnutls](http://gnutls.org/).

Answer (score 1):

Depending on what telnet you have available to you, there may be a -4 or -6 switch to restrict the IP version forcefully, allowing you to rule in or out the IPv4 vs IPv6 concern.

What does the netstat -arn output look like? Are there IPv6 routes for the destination and/or default IPv6 route that is viable?

Answer (score 0):

```
Connected to athena.hidden.tld.
```

Looks like you're connecting via hostname. Try using IP address to eliminate the possibility of DNS issues:

```
openssl s_client -connect puppet.master.ip.address:8140
```

Comment: that does not help either:

    openssl s_client -connect puppet.master.ip.address:8140
    connect: No route to host
    connect:errno=113

Comment: updated the description with details

Answer (score 0):

You have to check the versions of openssl.  There is an odd error out there that reports 113...if you dig a little deeper you may see a "handshake" problem....IIRC, 0.9.8 had the problem...if you are at that rev. or below...try updating your openssl.

Check this out...
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8619706/running-curl-with-openssl-0-9-8-against-openssl-1-0-0-server-causes-handshake-er/8621263#8621263